# Color difference from xaml wpf to html

Tags: html, css, wpf

I have an app made in WPF, now I'm writing it in HTML, CSS, and javascript.

I noticed that the colors are different even using the same WPF.

The HTML color seems to be lighter than WPF, follow the image below

[image]

I use it in CSS, as follows:

```
.TextTest {
   color: #0066CC;
}
```

What should I do to make the stronger color equal is in WPF

Comment: The font color of your WPF example seems to be #0066cc. It is exactly what it supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

Probably due to the difference between the wpf rendering engine and the browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).